# How to set a custom domain for Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: dns, azure-virtual-machine, cname

I have an Azure Virtual Machine which has `myvmname.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` set as a DNS name. I want it to be something like `somename.my.domain.com`. I am an owner of `my.domain.com`. How do I change it on the portal for the VM? Did I get stuck with default provided one? Docs are not clear for VMs.

Comment: Do you have any question in my reply?

Comment: Just wondering if it can be visibly changed in the VM resource. I know it's possible with the App Services. How do you think @NancyXiong ?

Comment: no there is no such feature in azure vm resource

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NancyXiong. I will notify you if everything is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure VM has a [default FQDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn) that you only could change the DNS label. If you want to add your own custom domain for that Azure VM, you could add a `CNAME` type DNS record like  `somename.my.domain.com CNAME myvmname.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` or `A` type record like `somename.my.domain.com A your Azure VM public IP address` in your DNS domain `my.domain.com` provider.

You also could select to [host your domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns), then you can manage your DNS records on Azure portal. See [this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-domain-name-to-azure-vm-using-dns-zone/) for more details.

Comment: Nancy, can you let know where to add this CNAME or A type DNS record? Do you mean we  can add "Record set" under my DNS zone? Btw, my custom domain is bought via Azure.

Comment: You can search "App Service Domains" in your azure search bar, then you can find the purchased domain, then you can add records in the ''manage DNS records"

Comment: Thanks Nancy for your response! I cannot find anything by searching for "App Service Domains". But I do find my domain as "DNS zone" under "All resources".  How can I apply this custom domain to my linux VM?

Comment: I created an A record under this DNS zone. but it seems not working. Btw, I don't have HTTP server for now. My application server is listening on port 80. I paste a screen shot of my record set under my DNS zone. Please see below.