# Azure DNS for Public IP

Tags: azure, dns, azure-dns

I have your VM public ip address

`xxx1.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`

I want to add 1 TXT record in DNS, for this purpose I created the following DNS zone

`xxx1.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`

then added 1 record

`test TXT 3600 TEST`

however i can't solve it

`dig TXT +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats xxx1.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com. @8.8.4.4`
`northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com. 60 IN SOA ns1-201.azure-dns.com. msnhst.microsoft.com. 10001 900 300 604800 60`

I can only resolve with the zone's name server: ns1-02.azure-dns.com.

`dig TXT +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats xxx1.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com. @ns1-02.azure-dns.com.`
`northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com. 300 IN SOA ns1-02.azure-dns.com. azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com. 1 3600 300 2419200 300`

I can't solve it from outside

what could be the problem?

I hope to get TEST DNS record

Comment: I don't think you can add DNS records to that zone since you don't control it. You'd need a custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

The issue usually occurs if you have not updated the name servers for DNS zone to point to the Azure DNS name servers.

In virtual machine make sure to change public Ip in  ***static***  like below:

[image]

Create a DNS zone with the same name of domain add name server.

[image]

Update the name servers for your domain like below:

```c
ns1-02.azure-dns.com
ns2-02.azure-dns.net
ns3-02.azure-dns.org
ns4-02.azure-dns.info
```

The changes to the name servers may take some time to reach all of the DNS servers on the internet after you make changes. Refer  [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-domain-name-to-azure-vm-using-dns-zone/)  by  *GOWTHAM K*.

[image]

You can use  `dig +trace TXT test.xxx1.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`  query is being resolved step by step any misconfigurations in the DNS.

In DNS record map @ and type A alias TTL and Ip address and you can add subdomain www as canonical name record, txt record and validate:

[image]

Now, when I ran  `nslookup`  it properly shows public Ip address and name server successfully like below:

[image]

***References***:

[dns - How to set a custom domain for Azure Virtual Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183580/how-to-set-a-custom-domain-for-azure-virtual-machine)  by Nancy

[Integrate Azure DNS with your Azure resources - Azure DNS | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain)